# Retain count incrementing by 2 in Instruments

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

How can the retain count of an object increment by a factor of 2 in Instruments?

Please take a look at the instruments screenshot below.

In #10 the retain count is 3. In # 11 an autorelease happens, which does not affect the retain count. In # 12, a retain happens, which should put the retain count at 4, but instead it is showing at 5.

How can this be possible? Any ideas?

[image: Instruments screenshot]

Comment: retain count does not mean anything. if no leak, no crash, it is good

Comment: I am trying to debug a leak. The retain count at the end of the life cycle is 1, and thus never gets released. I am trying to track down by looking at the Retain/Release history of the object, who is doing the extra retain.

Comment: try static analys in Xcode, under menu - Product - Analyze or shift+command+B

Comment: I figured out that my object was being dealloc because I was in a secondary thread that did not have an autorelease pool. However, I don't know why the Autorelease would bump the count +1.

Comment: thats the reason why retainCount is useless. calling `[[obj retain] autorelease]` will increase retain count by one, but the actual retain count is balanced